# ios - how to call ViewController.swift class from objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

***ViewController.swift***

```
    @IBOutlet weak var showLabel: UILabel!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    /* - commented out
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    */
    .
    .
    .
```

***ReadData.m***

```
    #import <DemoApp-Swift.h>

    @implementation ReadData

    -(void) getData {

        ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        controller.showLabel.text = @“xxxx”;
    .
    .
    .
    NSString* updateText = @"xxxxx";
    [controller.showLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:updateText waitUntilDone:NO];

    }
    .
    .
    .
```

While run, the below run time fatal error occurred.

```
../DemoApp/ViewController.swift: 20: 7: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'DemoApp.ViewController'
```

I want to update the label value in objective-c which I initialised in swift.
Have any idea...plz help me to fix it...

Thank you.

Comment: If added this method in ViewController.swift - fatal error gone. But label not updated..... override init() { super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) }

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are working in swift than use

class ReadData: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
  fun getData{

   let controller: ViewController = ViewController()
   controller.showLabel.text = "XXXXX"

  }

}
```

Comment: If in swift, its works good. But I want call it from Objective-c only.

Comment: is label add from storyboard than use

ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];

before this you can viewcontroller indentifier in storyboard

Comment: "ReadData.m" don't have "UIViewController".not connected with storyboard. This objective-c class mainly for data calculation only...